# How does @supports handle vendor prefixed queries?

Tags: css, cross-browser, flexbox, media-queries

When `@supports` evaluates a key/value pair for CSS spec support, would browsers that support only the vendor-prefixed variant of that CSS declaration apply the styles within the `@supports` block?

For example, IE10 recognizes `-ms-flex: flex` but not `display: flex`. Assuming IE10 were to also recognize the `@supports` declaration, would IE10 apply code styles within a `@supports (display: flex){}` block?

Comment: Can you provide an example? I'm having a hard time understanding what you are asking...but if I think I have you right, looking into a normalize library will ease your pains with vendor specific code

Comment: @LuisBrazilva Here's a contrived situation http://jsfiddle.net/Zacc206/m1jqr68r/. I'm specifically interested in how the key/value pair is evaluated and if vendor-prefixed variants are included in the evaluation of the non-prefixed property. For this contrived example it doesn't work because feature queries aren't supported in IE10, so I'm wondering what happens in the case that a browser supports feature queries and a prefixed CSS declaration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When *@supports* evaluates a key/value pair for CSS spec support, would
>   browsers that support only the vendor-prefixed variant of that CSS
>   declaration apply the styles within the *@supports* block?

No, you need to add the prefixed values as well, and `@supports` handle them in its query as any other property.

And it make sense, as what if you only wanted to target those without a prefix?

---

Here is a sample from https://drafts.csswg.org/css-conditional-3/#at-supports

> ```
> .noticebox {
>   border: 1px solid black;
>   padding: 1px;
> }
> @supports ( box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset ) or
>           ( -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset ) or
>           ( -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset ) or
>           ( -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset ) {
>   .noticebox {
>     -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset;
>     -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset;
>     -o-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset;
>     box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset; /* unprefixed last */
>     /* override the rule above the @supports rule */
>     border: none;
>     padding: 2px;
>   }
> }
> ```

Comment: So the vendor-prefixed key/value pairs also need to be passed to the feature query? Meaning that `@supports ( box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset )` is checked strictly against that exact key/value pair and `-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 2px black inset` is not also derived from it?

Comment: @ZachB Yes, and updated my answer to make that clear